# Como actualizar una columna dependiendo a otras columnas de otra tabla?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, trigger, update

Por si no le entendieron al titulo, necesito **Crear un disparador para que DESPUÉS de que se actualice algún registro de la tabla calificaciones, se calcule el promedio general (campo promgral) de la tabla alumnos.**

[image: Tabla calificaciones]

Esta es la tabla de calificaciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta la de alumnos.

Lo que pide es que cuando se actualice algún valor de la tabla de calificaciones, genere un promedio de las diferentes materias que tiene el alumno en la columna `promgral`.

Alguien que me explique como hacerle.

Lo único que se me a ocurrido es:

```
UPDATE alumnos 
SET alumnos.promgral=AVG( calificaciones.materia1/calificaciones.materia2/calificaciones.materia3/calificaciones.materia4/calificaciones.materia5/calificaciones.materia6/calificaciones.materia7 ) 
WHERE alumnos.idalumno=calificaciones.idalumno
```

pero esta mal.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta la exportacion

```
CREATE TRIGGER `calificaciones_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `calificaciones` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE alumnos SET alumnos.promgral=AVG( calificaciones.materia1/calificaciones.materia2/calificaciones.materia3/calificaciones.materia4/calificaciones.materia5/calificaciones.materia6/calificaciones.materia7)WHERE alumnos.idalumno=calificaciones.idalumno
```

Comment: Podrías indicar que has intentado hacer?

Comment: la verdad no le e echo nada, por que no entiendo como iria

Comment: Te recomiendo que investigues un poco el tema de los disparadores o triggers, te comparto una ruta donde te van a explicar a detalle, https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/triggers_mysql y https://www.neoguias.com/como-crear-y-utilizar-triggers-en-mysql/ Espero te sirva, prueba a ver como te va.

Comment: Primero haz una consulta para calcular el promedio de un alumno, sin pensar en el disparador o el update.